# How to get index and size of first non-singleton dimension?

Tags: matlab

If we consider a function that is meant to operate on the first non-singleton dimension of a matrix, is there a direct way to find the size and index of this non-singleton dimension? For instance, if the user inputs a matrix of size `1, N, M`, is there a function that could output that the first non-singleton dimension is `2` with size `N`?

In other words, is there a function that would return directly the first non-singleton dimension `fnsd` and first non-singleton size `fnss` as in the code below?

```matlab
% create matrix with two singleton dims first
x = rand(1, 1, 10, 20);

% find the first non-singleton dimension
fnsd = find(size(x) > 1, 1);

% get the first non-singleton size
fuss = size(x, fnsd);
```

Comment: So you come from R eh? MATLAB doesn’t use such a function. To implement behavior such as that from `sum` or `max`, you can use `shiftdim` with one input argument. Note the second output argument, which you can use to add back the singleton dimensions to your output.